# Job pool in linux bash with php processes

Tags: php, bash, parallel-processing

I need to have a pool in my `bash-script` of the same `php` process. The pool must contain 10 processes and as soon as a job is finished in the pool a new one must start in order to always run 10 processes in parallel. I'm really new to bash scripting so I need some help to get started.

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at GNU Parallel - [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) with documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

To do what you want, you can create a file with a job queue in it, initially empty like this:

```
# Clear queue out
> jobqueue
```

Then you can start processing jobs, with no more than 10 at a time like this:

```
tail -f jobqueue | parallel -j 10
```

Then you go in another terminal window, but in the same directory and submit a job like this:

```
echo "sleep 5;date" >> jobqueue
```

or, if your jobs are PHP scripts, maybe you will do something like this:

```
echo "./myscript.php" >> jobqueue
```

Or, you can submit 40 jobs like this:

```
for i in {1..40}; do echo "sleep 5;date +'%H:%M:%S Job $i'"; done >> jobqueue
```

Or, totally different suggestion, if you already have a file with an already known list of 1000's of jobs in it, you can forget the jobqueue file I was suggesting above and submit them all in one go to be run 10 at a time like this:

```
parallel -j 10 < joblist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `parallel`, you could try something like :

```
# loop ...
if [[ $(jobs -p|wc -l) -ge 10 ]]; the
    wait "$(jobs -p|head -1)" || echo "Job ended with failure"
fi
./your_script &
# end loop ...
```